# Could not complete oAuth2.0 login

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, postman, asp.net-core-2.0, openid-connect

I have implemented Aspnet.security.openidconnect.server with .net core 2.1 app. Now I want to test my authorization and for that I am making postman request. If I change the grant type to client_credentials then it works but I want to test complete flow, so I select grant type to Authorzation code and it starts giving error "Could not complete oAuth2.0 login.

Here is the code:

```
    services.AddAuthentication(OAuthValidationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddOAuthValidation()
            .AddOpenIdConnectServer(options =>
            {
                options.AuthorizationEndpointPath = new PathString(AuthorizePath);
                // Enable the token endpoint.
                options.TokenEndpointPath = new PathString(TokenPath);
                options.ApplicationCanDisplayErrors = true;
                options.AccessTokenLifetime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
#if DEBUG
                 options.AllowInsecureHttp = true;
#endif
                options.Provider.OnValidateAuthorizationRequest = context =>
                {
                    if (string.Equals(context.ClientId, Configuration["OpenIdServer:ClientId"], StringComparison.Ordinal))
                    {
                        context.Validate(context.RedirectUri);
                    }
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };
                // Implement OnValidateTokenRequest to support flows using the token endpoint.
                options.Provider.OnValidateTokenRequest = context =>
                {
                // Reject token requests that don't use grant_type=password or grant_type=refresh_token.
                if (!context.Request.IsClientCredentialsGrantType() && !context.Request.IsPasswordGrantType()
                    && !context.Request.IsRefreshTokenGrantType())
                    {
                        context.Reject(
                       error: OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.UnsupportedGrantType,
                       description: "Only grant_type=password and refresh_token " +
                                    "requests are accepted by this server.");

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }

                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.ClientId))
                    {
                        context.Skip();

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }

                    if (string.Equals(context.ClientId, Configuration["OpenIdServer:ClientId"], StringComparison.Ordinal) &&
                        string.Equals(context.ClientSecret, Configuration["OpenIdServer:ClientSecret"], StringComparison.Ordinal))
                    {
                        context.Validate();
                    }

                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };

                // Implement OnHandleTokenRequest to support token requests.
                options.Provider.OnHandleTokenRequest = context =>
                {
                 // Only handle grant_type=password token requests and let
                 // the OpenID Connect server handle the other grant types.
                 if (context.Request.IsClientCredentialsGrantType() || context.Request.IsPasswordGrantType())
                    {
                     //var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Scheme.Name,
                     //    OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Name,
                     //    OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Role);
                     ClaimsIdentity identity = null;
                        if (context.Request.IsClientCredentialsGrantType())
                        {
                            identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new GenericIdentity(context.Request.ClientId, "Bearer"), context.Request.GetScopes().Select(x => new Claim("urn:oauth:scope", x)));
                        }
                        else if (context.Request.IsPasswordGrantType())
                        {
                            identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new GenericIdentity(context.Request.Username, "Bearer"), context.Request.GetScopes().Select(x => new Claim("urn:oauth:scope", x)));
                        }
                     // Add the mandatory subject/user identifier claim.
                     identity.AddClaim(OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject, Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n") + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n"));

                     // By default, claims are not serialized in the access/identity tokens.
                     // Use the overload taking a "destinations" parameter to make sure
                     // your claims are correctly inserted in the appropriate tokens.
                     identity.AddClaim("urn:customclaim", "value",
                     OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.AccessToken,
                     OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.IdentityToken);

                        var ticket = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationTicket(
                         new ClaimsPrincipal(identity),
                         new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationProperties(),
                         context.Scheme.Name);

                     // Call SetScopes with the list of scopes you want to grant
                     // (specify offline_access to issue a refresh token).
                     ticket.SetScopes(
                         OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.Profile,
                         OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.OfflineAccess);

                        context.Validate(ticket);
                    }

                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };
```

and here is the postman collection:

[image]

Now I am not sure that whether the issue is in my code or in postman collection? I think the callback url is creating some issue but I am not sure. Any help?

Update:

By visiing this page https://kevinchalet.com/2016/07/13/creating-your-own-openid-connect-server-with-asos-implementing-the-authorization-code-and-implicit-flows/ I have found the issue. I haven't handled authorization code flow in my code but I even don't want to. Is there any way I test my code with Resource owner password? I can't see this grant type in request form. In simple words I want postman to open login screen which is in Controller/Login/Index and I select my ssl Certificate and it generates a token for me?

Answer (score 0):

hello i think that you have to add https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback as the redirect_url in your server config, i don't think that your STS server will return tokens back to a non trusted url. that's why it works from your app but not from Postman

Comment: thanks for your answer. But if see "Update" section of my question, I was not handling Authorization Code flow in my ASOS server. Now I want to test my code in a way I mentioned in "Update" section of my question